# How to split a name string with multiple spaces?

Tags: javascript

i want to sort firstname and lastname, my problem is when the user has multiple first name, e.g.:

```
'Michael Jordan Atticus Smith'
```

basically, the Smith is the last name there, how do i split firstname and lastname with it? the result i want from  is:

```
'Michael Jordan Atticus' 'Smith'
```

Comment: The problem is unsolvable in general. What if the user has multiple last names, say  first name 'Michael Jordan', last name 'Atticus Smith'?

Comment: most of the time it'd be just smith, can't think of solution though, i googled already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = 'Michael Jordan Atticus Smith';

console.log( ex1(str) );
console.log( ex2(str) );
console.log( ex3(str) );

function ex1(str) {
  let names = str.match(/(.*?)\s(\S+)$/); // (1)
  return [ names[1], names[2] ];
}

function ex2(str) {
  let names = str.split(" ");
  return [names.pop(), names.join(" ")].reverse(); // (2)
}

function ex3(str) {
  let last = ""
  str = str.replace(/\s(\S+)$/, function(full_match, parenthesis_1) {
    last = parenthesis_1;
    return "";
  });
  
  return [str, last];
}
```

**(1)** `match()` returns an array of matched strings. Also, see the [RegEx cheet sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

**(2)** Array `pop()` method removes, and **returns** the last element. Code executes from the left to right, so, the second `names.join(" ")` collects together 3 names left.